# What encryption is it?

Tags: encoding, reverse-engineering, packet

I used EtherDetect to see what is one game sending to me and what I'm sending to game server.
I was wondering what encryption is it after the packet information which is colored in grey color in the image bellow. How can I encrypt/decrypt information which I'm sending/receiving in my games like this?

[image: ehterdetect]

Comment: Do you have a binary viewer that can tell you (based on cursor position) what the byte/short/int/DWORD/float/double values are?  Do that and look for recognizable patterns.  Several years ago I reverse-engineered the 3D object and image formats for a game doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you think this data is encrypted? This could also be simple binary encoded data, but as long as you don't know the data format this remains a secret.

Comment: Alright, I took a wrong word - I meant encoding rather than encryption.

Answer (score 1):

probably be better off googling about the game, find out what game engine it uses, etc etc, this is probably the easist way to work it out.

edit - Looking at the data, there is some strings in there, so it's probably not encrypted. As the other answer states, it may just be binary representations of data only meaningful if you know what it is... could be a few numbers, could mean the state of the game, state of a player, location updates.. who knows?

Comment: This applies to @splash too - I think you're both right that it's probably just binary data.  Given the need for performance above almost everything else (from a network perspective, anyway) I would think it's pretty rare for a game to encrypt data on the wire.  Encryption and decryption are expensive operations to perform, and can result in larger data on the wire than the input - neither of which are desirable.

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant encoding or data type (like binary or something). This is quite new to me so I didn't quite know how to call it. Anyone maybe knows how to make a data binary lets say in Flash?

Answer (score 0):

The "encryption" is your ethernet & ip header...